# Unable to inline iFrame with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have an API response that is returning an iFrame embed which I'd like to include within my React application. The return looks like this which is set to the property of `this.props.thread.data.secure_media_embed.content`

```
<iframe class="embedly-embed" src="https://...." width="600" height="1067" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have setup a function to render this type of content like so:

```
renderExpandableContent() {
    const { thread } = this.props;

    if (thread.data.post_hint == 'image') {
        return <img src={thread.data.url} className="img-responsive" />;

    } else if (thread.data.post_hint == 'rich:video') {
        return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: thread.data.secure_media_embed.content } } />;
    }
};
```

The problem I'm having is that the iFrame ends up rendering on the page as a string and not the actual iFrame. Is there something I'm missing here or another way to handle this type of content? I've followed several instructions on using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but none seem to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proof of concept

So assuming that is actually what you're returning, what you're doing should work. Here is an example I've created: https://codesandbox.io/s/o7jn8k9m79.

### So why isn't it working?

My guess is that the server is html encoding the content you're getting back. Try console logging (or inspecting the raw response) and see if what you're getting bak is literally:

```
<iframe class="embedly-embed" src...></iframe>
```

or if it's something like this:

```
&lt;iframe class=&quot;embedly-embed&quot; src...&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

If it's the latter than you'll need to not escape the content you're returning.

### A better way to do things

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is as the name suggests **dangerous**. In your particular case nothing dangerous seems to be happening (unless the properties of the iframe can be controlled by user input in which case you'll likely have XSS). But as codebases increase and more developers come on board, it's better to outright ban the use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (or severely limit it) and use alternatives where possible.

Instead of having your server return raw html, I'd recommend returning the values of the attributes that are dynamically set in a JS object like this:

```
{
    src: 'https://...',
    width: 600,
    height: 1067
}
```

and then (assuming this object is set as a variable called `iframeProps`) in your react returning something like this:

```
return <iframe
       className='embedly-embed'
       scrolling='no'
       frameborder='0'
       allowfullscreen 
       { ...iframeProps }
       />;
```

Using the [ES6 spread operator](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html). Alternatively you could also set `src={ iframeProps.src }` as well for each dynamically set attribute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's the later you are correct, how do I handle this type if adjusting the server format isn't an option?

Comment: So in that case you'll need to html decode the string. One way to do that is like this: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = thread.data.secure_media_embed.content; var decodedHTML = d.innerText;` and now `decodedHTML` will be the actual string you want

Comment: @JamesIves if this is the correct answer would you mind marking it as such? Thanks